# remove div of page loaded in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm completely new to javascript and need some assistance. I need to remove a div element from another page which is shown on mine through an `<iframe>`.

This is my page's code

```
<html>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript">
    </script>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="PAGE HERE"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to remove this Div element of another webpage

```
<div comp="removepls">
```

**EDIT**

**CANNOT EDIT EXTERNAL WEBSITES WHICH ARE NOT HOSTED ON YOUR SERVER**

Comment: is that 'other page' coming from the same domain as your page? If not, you can't manipulate the contents of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `src` of the `iframe` is not from the same domain and using the same protocol as the page it is rendered in, then you will not be able to access that content. This violates the `same-origin policy` and is a security feature in all modern browsers. If the `iframe` contains a page you created with the same domain and protocol, then you can query for the `iframe` with jQuery just like any other `DOM` element: `$('iframe')` or you could also give the `iframe` a class or ID and query for it that way.

Comment: So there's no way of changing the content of the page? Are there any work a rounds for it?

Comment: please be clear in your question... if the page you are loading in the frame in on your website that you control or loading from another external website?   If from another site, like cnn.com, then no, there isn't a way around it.

Comment: @donlaur Yeah, it's and external website. Alright, thank you!

Comment: @user3499401 Yes, that's correct. Also, you will not be able to screw around with `z-index` or anything at all. If you put an `iframe` on your page, it will display how the provider wants it to display, bottom line lol. Think about it: if you created a page and your HTML had an iframe for some bank website, should you be able to access that site's cookies? Do you think this is safe? This is the reason why.

Comment: What if the embed div is from the same website?
How can you remove a div from the embed iframe?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('iframe').contents().find("div[comp='removepls']").remove();
```

That should find and remove the oddly attributed div.

Comment: Yes, why what is the comp part?  Odd.

Comment: @donlaur A custom `DOM` attribute. The convention is to prefix any custom attributes with 'data-' so it should read 'data-comp', but it will still render this way.